# ASP.net session state service information

Tags: asp.net, service, state

Where can you get information on the ASP.NET State Service e.g. how it works, performance, behaviour characteristics etc.
Have looked on internet but cant find in depth information or an article dedicated to the subject.
Thanks

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349503/aspnet-session-state-service-information

Comment: Closed. Dupe. Comments posted to those that contributed to move posts.

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically, session state is nothing more than memory in the shape of a dictionary or hash table, e.g. key-value pairs, which can be set and read for the duration of a user's session.

Check following links for more details:

- "[ASP.NET Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx)" on MSDN
- "[Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28VS.80%29.aspx)" on MSDN

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server State Management remember that you don't call `Session["Key"]` in loops. (Try to avoid that) Because everytime it accesses the session then a roundtrip to sqlserver is made.

Comment: You may want to re-post this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349503/aspnet-session-state-service-information